# Set column name for apply result over groupby

Tags: python, pandas

This is a fairly trivial problem, but its triggering my OCD and I haven't been able to find a suitable solution for the past half hour.

For background, I'm looking to calculate a value (let's call it F) for each group in a DataFrame derived from *different* aggregated measures of columns in the existing DataFrame.

Here's a toy example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X'],
                'B': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'N'],
                'C': [69, 83, 28, 25, 11, 31, 14, 37, 14,  0],
                'D': [ 0.3,  0.1,  0.1,  0.8,  0.8,  0. ,  0.8,  0.8,  0.1,  0.8],
                'E': [11, 11, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12]
                })

df_grp = df.groupby(['A','B'])
df_grp.apply(lambda x: x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max())
```

What I'd like to do is assign a name to the result of `apply` (or `lambda`). Is there anyway to do this without moving `lambda` to a named function or renaming the column after running the last line?

Comment: What is your expected output for the toy data?

Comment: `5.583333, 2.975000, 3.845455`, which is what the function returns.

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29778475/2137255 ?

Comment: Essentially. Is there a way of assigning a name to the result short of defining the function? I'd prefer to use `lambda`.

Comment: Actually, looking at that link again, its not exactly what I want. I need the result at the group level only, not the original DataFrame.

Comment: Ah, not sure yet, but guess this works `df_grp.apply(lambda x: x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max()).reset_index(name='your_col_name')` ? Basically, here you are converting your `series` result to a `dataframe` and `name`ing it.

Comment: That works, and is far better than the alternatives. Do you want to submit it as an answer and I'll check it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could convert your `series` to a `dataframe` using `reset_index()` and provide `name='yout_col_name'` -- The name of the column corresponding to the Series values

```
(df_grp.apply(lambda x: x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max())
      .reset_index(name='your_col_name'))

   A  B  your_col_name
0  X  N   5.583333
1  Y  M   2.975000
2  Y  N   3.845455
```

Comment: This answer worked better for me than the accepted one.

Comment: If you happen to stop by again sometime - a bit of prose about what's going on with that `reset_index()` would be additionally helpful

Comment: apparently the `name` parameter has been removed. maybe it's `names` now - given more recent `multi-index` support

Comment: @WestCoastProjects No idea where the `name` comes from & why it works. \
Some docs shows it has something to do with index, but I dont see any relation?

Answer (score 49):

Have the lambda function return a new Series:

```
df_grp.apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'new_name':
                    x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max()}))
# or df_grp.apply(lambda x: x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max()).to_frame('new_name')

     new_name
A B          
X N  5.583333
Y M  2.975000
  N  3.845455
```

Comment: This sort of thing makes me miss R.    But, +1, thanks.

Comment: Not efficient. Ex:; computing certain groupby.apply went from 1'32'' up to 2'32'' if a pd.Series with name is used for each iteration as in this answer

Comment: > Please be aware of the huge memory consumption and low speed. \
(Talked in other posts.) \
(This could be a good way if pandas fix this.) \

python - Pandas Apply Function That returns two new columns - Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969756/pandas-apply-function-that-returns-two-new-columns

How Not to Use pandas' "apply"
https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer seems work for the current version of Pandas, but `name` is not one of the parameters of `reset_index` according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). There is a `names` argument, but it serves a different purpose IMO.

Since the output of apply is a series, we can simply use [pandas.Series.rename()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) to achive the result.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X'],
                'B': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N', 'M', 'N'],
                'C': [69, 83, 28, 25, 11, 31, 14, 37, 14,  0],
                'D': [ 0.3,  0.1,  0.1,  0.8,  0.8,  0. ,  0.8,  0.8,  0.1,  0.8],
                'E': [11, 11, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12]
                })

df_grp = df.groupby(['A','B'])
df_grp.apply(lambda x: x['C'].sum() * x['D'].mean() / x['E'].max()).rename("your_col_name")
```

Comment: The output of `apply` can be either a DataFrame or a Series ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html))