# Pandas Apply Function That returns two new columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe that I would like to use an apply function on to generate two new columns based on the existing data. I am getting this error: 
`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunc1(row):
    C = row['A'] + 10
    D = row['A'] + 50
    return [C, D]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(2, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

df['C', 'D'] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)
```

Starting DF:

```
   A  B
0  6  1
1  8  4
```

Desired DF:

```
   A  B  C   D
0  6  1  16  56
1  8  4  18  58
```

Comment: Make it `df[['C', 'D']]`

Comment: Does your function always need two columns as input?

Comment: @coldspeed, the dataframe passed could be many columns, but only two needed for the calculation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your latest error, you can avoid the error by returning the new columns as a Series

```
def myfunc1(row):
    C = row['A'] + 10
    D = row['A'] + 50
    return pd.Series([C, D])

df[['C', 'D']] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)
```

Comment: Please be aware of the huge memory consumption and low speed of the accepted answer, alternative solution below

Answer (score 10):

It works for me:

```
def myfunc1(row):
    C = row['A'] + 10
    D = row['A'] + 50
    return C, D

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(2, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

df[['C', 'D']] = df.apply(myfunc1, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df
```

add: ==>> result_type='expand',

regards!

Comment: Just had this problem and adding `, result_type='expand'` was the only way I could get this to work, thank you

Comment: I think this is the easiest way, thanks!

Comment: This seems more "pythonic" than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Please be aware of the huge memory consumption and low speed of the accepted answer: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/ !

Using the suggestion presented there, the correct answer would be like this:

```
def run_loopy(df):
    Cs, Ds = [], []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        c, d, = myfunc1(row['A'])
        Cs.append(c)
        Ds.append(d)
    return pd.Series({'C': Cs,
                      'D': Ds})

def myfunc1(a):
    c = a + 10
    d = a + 50
    return c, d

df[['C', 'D']] = run_loopy(df)
```

Comment: I think you should edit `Cs, Ds = [], []` (1st row of `run_loopy`) to `v1s, v2s = [], []` or vice versa

Comment: @codkelden Thanks for noticing! I will change v1s and v2s to Cs and Ds, so whoever reads it understands quickly we are talking about the columns

Comment: This is indeed much faster

Answer (score 3):

`df['C','D']` is considered as 1 column rather than 2. So for 2 columns you need a sliced dataframe so use `df[['C','D']]`

```
df[['C', 'D']] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)

    A  B   C   D
0  4  6  14  54
1  5  1  15  55
```

Or you can use chain assignment i.e

```
df['C'], df['D'] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked on my example dataset (so upvoted), but does not work on my real dataset despite identical code. Error: `KeyError: "['C' 'D'] not in index"`

Comment: I need to see how you are assigning the data. Your actual code perhaps.

Comment: Same way, the only code that is difference is reading in a dataframe from CSV vs using numpy to generate fake data `df[['C', 'D']] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)`

Comment: Your myfunc1 is same as the above?

Comment: @user2242044. Your error message shows that there is a missing comma between ‘C’ and ‘D’.

Comment: @Goose you know if you dont pass a comma it will be considered as a single string like `'CD'`. Sometimes assignment wont work. Hard to remember the cases.

Answer (score 2):

I believe can achieve similar results to @Federico Dorato answer without use of for loop. Return a list rather than a series and use lambda-apply + to_list() to expand results.

It's cleaner code and on a random df of 10,000,000 rows performs as well or faster.

### Federico's code

```
run_time = []

for i in range(0,25):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000000,size=(2, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
    def run_loopy(df):
        Cs, Ds = [], []
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            c, d, = myfunc1(row['A'])
            Cs.append(c)
            Ds.append(d)
        return pd.Series({'C': Cs,
                        'D': Ds})

    def myfunc1(a):
        c = a / 10
        d = a + 50
        return c, d

    start = time.time()
    df[['C', 'D']] = run_loopy(df)
    end = time.time()

    run_time.append(end-start) 
print(np.average(run_time)) # 0.001240386962890625
```

### Using lambda and to_list

```
run_time = []

for i in range(0,25):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10000000,size=(2, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

    def myfunc1(a):
        c = a / 10
        d = a + 50
        return [c, d]

    start = time.time()
    df[['C', 'D']] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: myfunc1(x)).to_list()
    end = time.time()
run_time.append(end-start)
print(np.average(run_time)) #output 0.0009996891021728516
```

Answer (score 1):

Add extra brackets when querying for multiple columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def myfunc1(row):
    C = row['A'] + 10
    D = row['A'] + 50
    return [C, D]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(2, 2)), columns=list('AB'))

df[['C', 'D']] = df.apply(myfunc1 ,axis=1)
```