# Conditional mean over a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, mean, nan

I have a dataset from which I want a few averages of multiple variables I created.

I started off with:

```
data2['socialIdeology2'].mean()

data2['econIdeology'].mean()
```

^ that works perfectly, and gives me the averages I'm looking for.

Now, I'm trying to do a conditional mean, so the mean only for a select group within the data set. (I want the ideologies broken down by whom voted for in the 2016 election) In Stata, the code would be similar to: `mean(variable) if voteChoice == 'Clinton'`

Looking into it, I came to the conclusion a conditional mean just isn't a thing (although hopefully I am wrong?), so I was writing my own function for it.

This is me just starting out with a 'mean' function, to create a foundation for a conditional mean function:

```
def mean():
    sum = 0.0
    count = 0
    for index in range(0, len(data2['socialIdeology2'])):
        sum = sum + (data2['socialIdeology2'][index])
        print(data2['socialIdeology2'][index])
        count = count + 1
    return sum / count

print(mean())
```

Yet I keep getting 'nan' as the result. Printing `data2['socialIdeology2'][index]` within the loop prints `nan` over and over again.

So my question is: if the data stored within the `socialIdeology2` variable really is a `nan` (which I don't understand how it could be), why is it that the `.mean()` function works with it?

And how can I get generate means by category?

Comment: Are you using NumPy? It looks more like Pandas. Which is built on top of NumPy, but is different.

Comment: I'm using Pandas, yeah! Sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Panda dataframe conditional .mean() depending on values in certain column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778370/panda-dataframe-conditional-mean-depending-on-values-in-certain-column)

Comment: Is there a way to do it for variance or covariance ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Conditional mean is indeed a thing in pandas.  You can use [`DataFrame.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
means = data2.groupby('voteChoice').mean()
```

or maybe, in your case, the following would be more efficient:

```
means = data2.groupby('voteChoice')['socialIdeology2'].mean()
```

to drill down to the mean you're looking for.  (The first case will calculate means for all columns.)  This is assuming that `voteChoice` is the name of the column you want to condition on.

Comment: Do you know how to do it for variance and covariance ?

Comment: instead of `.mean()` you'd use `.var()` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're only interested in the mean for a *single* group (e.g. Clinton voters) then you could create a boolean series that is True for members of that group, then use this to index into the rows of the DataFrame before taking the mean:

```
voted_for_clinton = data2['voteChoice'] == 'Clinton'
mean_for_clinton_voters = data2.loc[voted_for_clinton, 'socialIdeology2'].mean()
```

If you want to get the means for multiple groups simultaneously then you can use `groupby`, as in Brad's answer. However, I would do it like this:

```
means_by_vote_choice = data2.groupby('voteChoice')['socialIdeology2'].mean()
```

Placing the `['socialIdeology2']` index before the `.mean()` means that you only compute the mean over the column you're interested in, whereas if you place the indexing expression after the `.mean()` (i.e. `data2.groupby('voteChoice').mean()['socialIdeology2']`) this computes the means over *all* columns and then selects only the `'socialIdeology2'` column from the result, which is less efficient.

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) for more info on indexing DataFrames using `.loc` and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for more info on `groupby`.